# Error Updating Ubuntu 14.04 on new Install

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, upgrade, updates, windows

I downloaded a new copy of Ubuntu 14.04.3 and burned the iso to a USB flash drive.
I booted my computer, which was previously dual booted with Windows 10, and installed a new copy of Ubuntu over my existing copy. After the new isntall, I first ran

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Which ran and completed fine.

Then I ran

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Which ran and completed, but I was presented with the following message a few times during the output of the dist-upgrade run:

> (gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0:10971): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory
>
> This likely means that your installation is broken.
>   Try running the command
>     gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache
>   to make things work again for the time being.
>   Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...

I have tried this with Ubuntu 14.04.3 and Ubuntu 14.04.2, I've tried burning the ISO from 3 different computers and 3 different programs. I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given in the error-report you posted.

Simply run: `sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0` to make sure the folder is created.

Afterwards run `sudo gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cach‌​e` as mentioned in your question.

Now reissue your upgrade.

Yet this warning is of no bigger concern as it only relates to the gtk-icon-cache.